# Spring reactive vs Non reactive memory usage

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jvm, spring-webflux

From what i research about spring reactive, since the thread calling Tomcat Web Server is non blocking it should not consume too much heap memory. I am trying to use the traditional blocking non reactive model in retrieving data using spring data jpa to test ahat assumtion. Here is my code

```
 @GetMapping("/customers")
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        long beforeUsedMem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        List<Customer> customerList = customerRepository.findAll(); // Your operation here
        long afterUsedMem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Approximate memory used: " + (afterUsedMem - beforeUsedMem) + " bytes");

        return customerList;
    }
```

I am trying to measure the size of customerList (2 millions records in db)approximately its memory is about more than 1 GB
My output

```
Approximate memory used: 1371603632 bytes
```

I have two questions hopefully someone can help me answer.

1. Does the customerList suppose to be stored in heap memory ?. Does retrieving 2 millions records and stored them in a list suppose to cause out of memory runtime error ?. If the GB plays a role in prevent its crash then how does it do its job in resolving memory in this case since we have no "unused" memory ? When i ran the code it produced output fine
2. If I use reactive style in retrieving data

```
   @GetMapping("/")
   public Flux<Customer> getCustomers() {
       return customerRepository.findAll()
               .doOnNext(customer -> System.out.println(customer.getCustomer_name()));
   }
```

Will it have any improvement in term of memory usage ?

Comment: I found the answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems the maximum size for my heap is 4GB so i changed the maximum heap size to 1GB. It seems the blocking model cause out of memory heap size error

```
    @GetMapping("/customers")
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
        System.out.println("Maximum Heap Size: " + maxMemory / (1024 * 1024) + " MB");
        long beforeUsedMem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        List<Customer> customerList = customerRepository.findAll(); // Your operation here
        long afterUsedMem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Approximate memory used: " + (afterUsedMem - beforeUsedMem) + " bytes");

        return customerList;
    }
```

When i changed to reactive non blocking models, things works fine

```
    @GetMapping("/")
    public Flux<Customer> getCustomers() throws InterruptedException {
        long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
        System.out.println("Maximum Heap Size: " + maxMemory / (1024 * 1024) + " MB");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return customerRepository.findAll()
                .doOnNext(customer -> System.out.println(customer.getCustomer_name()));
    }
```

I am quite surprised the maximum heap size is 4 GB.
I guess i can draw up some conclusion about the advantage of using reactive programming model in this case